# Is the localization of a ring $R$ at a prime ideal a finitely generated algebra over $R$?

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring and let $S=\{1,s,s^2,s^3,\dots\}$ be a multiplicative system of $R$. Consider the canonical map $R\rightarrow S^{-1}R$. Is $S^{-1}R$ a finitely generated algebra over $R$? It looks like $\frac{1}{s}$ will generate $S^{-1}R$ over $R$.

> 1. If $P$ is a prime ideal of $R$, is $R_{P}$ a finitely generated algebra over $R$?
> 2. If instead of $S=\{1,s,s^2,s^3,\dots\}$ we take any arbitrary multiplicative system, is $S^{-1}R$  a finitely generated algebra over $R$?

Comment: You are correct in the first assumption. For the second, think of localizing a prime ideal in the integers.

Comment: So are you claiming $\mathbb{Z}_{P}$ is not finitely generated over $\mathbb{Z}$? I guess $\mathbb{Z}_{P}$ will have infinitely many elements of the form $\frac{a}{b}$ where p doesn't divide $p$. Now with ploynomial combinations of finitely many of them one cannot generate the whole of $\mathbb{Z}_{P}$. Is the argument correct?

Comment: Right (one way to think of it is that given a finite subset, you can only get a finite number of distinct prime divisors in the denominators).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft That should really be posted as an answer to the question.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft Instead of $S=\{1,s,s^2,s^3,\cdots\}$ if we take any multiplicative system, is the localization still finitely generated?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If $S$ is finitely generated as a monoid, then $S^{-1} R$ is finitely generated as an $R$-algebra. In fact, if $S$ is generated by $s_1,\dotsc,s_n$, then $S^{-1} R$ is generated by $\frac{1}{s_1},\dotsc,\frac{1}{s_n}$. If $S$ is not finitely generated, then usually $S^{-1} R$ is not finitely generated. This applies in particular to the case that $S=R \setminus \mathfrak{p}$ for some prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$. For instance, $\mathbb{Q}$ is not a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-algebra.

Comment: Can it happen that $S$ is not finitely generated but $S^{-1}R$ is still finitely generated as an $R$-algebra? I can't think of an example offhand.

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Yes, there are lots of trivial examples because if $0 \in S$ then $S^{-1} R = 0$.

Comment: But usually we disallow that. Are there examples without this? My guess would be that at least one would need to invert some zero divisors.

Comment: "usually we disallow that" - why? who?

Comment: Hmm, for some reason I remembered it as if that was part of the definition of a multiplicative set. Anyway, one can make similar "trivial" examples by only inverting units. I wonder if there are non-trivial examples (i.e. where the multiplicative set does not contain $0$ and the only unit it contains is $1$).