# Dimension of localizations as complex vector spaces.

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, artinian

Consider the ring $A=\mathbb{C}[x,y]/\left\langle x^2-y^3, 4y^2+x^4+5x^2y\right\rangle$. I proved that $A$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{C}$. More precisely
$$A=\langle \overline{1},\overline{x},\overline{y},\overline{y}^2,\overline{y}^3,\overline{y}^4,\overline{y}^5,\overline{x}\overline{y},\overline{x}\overline{y}^2,\overline{x}\overline{y}^3,\overline{x}\overline{y}^4,\overline{x}\overline{y}^5\rangle$$ Thus, $A$ is Artinian and its dimension is $12$. Furthermore, there are nine maximal ideals in $A$, which are of the form
$$\mathfrak{m}=(\overline{x-a},\overline{y-b})$$
for some $a,b\in \mathbb{C}$. Now, I am wondering for the dimension of $A_\mathfrak{m}$ for each maximal ideal $\mathfrak{m}$ as complex vector spaces, but I do not know how to find these.

Thank you in advance for your ideas.

Comment: Why do you think that $A_m$ is a finitely dimensional vector space?

Comment: Really, I am not sure, because I have elements of the form $1/(\overline{x-1})$ or $1/(\overline{x-y})$

Comment: Well, if it is, then $A_m$ is a finitely generated $A$-module, and this happens very seldom. Relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1060904 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2408931.

Answer (score 1):

Replace $x^2=y^3$ in $4y^2+x^4+5x^2y = y^2(y^2+1)(y^2+5)$, if $a\not=0\Leftrightarrow b\not=0$, it's clear that $b$ is not a repeated $0$ of $y$, and $x^2 - b^3=0$ has no repeated zero either. Therefore, $A_{\mathfrak m}\simeq \mathbb C[x,y]/\langle x-a, y-b\rangle\simeq\mathbb C$ has dimension $1$.

When $a=b=0$, then after the localization, the original ideal is the same as $\langle x^2, y^2\rangle$, and therefore the local ring has its maximal ideal generated by $\bar x,\bar y, \bar x \bar y$ over $\mathbb C$. Hence the dimension is $4$.

Comment: Sorry, I realized that I commited a typing mistake, the polynomial was $4y^2+x^4-5x^2y$. However, I think that the idea of your solution does not change.

Comment: I have one question. I am not sure why we have the isomorphism between the localization $A_\mathfrak{m}$ and the quotient and $\mathbb{C}/\left\langle x-a,y-b\right\rangle$.

Comment: Because if it's not a repeated zero, $(a,b)$ is a regular point, and therefore the local ring must be regular of dimension $0$. If you want an explicit way, as $b$ is a single zero of $y^2(y^2+1)(y^2+5)$, all the factors don't live in $\langle y-b \rangle$, except $y-b$, therefore after localization, they're all invertible, hence the generator is equivalent to $y-b$. Similar argument for $x-a$ holds.